# How would you translate “dark project” into Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How would you translate “dark project” into Latin, as in a secret project? I know *tenebris* means dark, but I’m having trouble finding the word for “project.”

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest *opus arcanum* meaning "secret task/secret work."

Some abridged definitions from Lewis & Short:

Opus:

> A. In gen., work, labor (cf.: “labor, ars, opera); B. Esp.
>   1. Work, art, workmanship
>   2. Of agricultural labor
>   4. Of literary labor
>   II. Transf., a work that has been done or made.

Arcanum (neuter to match the gender of *opus*):

> II. Hidden, concealed, secret, private (class., although very rare in Cic.) — “Esp., in the lang. of religion, of things sacred and incommunicable; “and of secret, mysterious usages: sacra,”; B. Spec., a sacred secret, a mystery

Comment: That has a nice ring to it!

Comment: @SimpliciterChristianus Well, *obscurus* was already taken! I am looking forward to seeing what you come up with for *project*, though.

Comment: I think your answer is perfect, and *opus* would certainly be a synonym of our English “project.” :) The only other one I would offer is (based on your adjective *arcanus*) *conatus*, as in *conatus arcanus*. But yours certainly has a better ring to it. I like that adjective, *arcanus*.

Comment: @SimpliciterChristianus I wouldn't delete your answer though! The more the merrier, and you say things that I don't.

Comment: @SimpliciterChristianus While Weimer's answer is good, yours is good, too. What yours has is an explanation of how the most obvious word, *proiectus*, probably did not have the desired meaning in classical Latin. I think it could be very helpful to (future) readers; it's such a pity that you deleted it!

Comment: Thanks everybody! What would "opus tenebris" mean then? A project conducted in the dark, literally?

Comment: @JonathanYandel That's a possible meaning, yes. Or one conducted for the dark. Or one conducted under the cover of darkness.